# how to fix web app low memory crashes on mobile safari

Tags: ipad, web-applications, safari, crash, low-memory

Our web app is generating LowMemory crashes very often on Ipad and Iphone.

This is an example from CrashReporter

```
Incident Identifier: 858042
CrashReporter Key:   6bda3a
Hardware Model:      iPad1,1
OS Version:          iPhone OS 5.0.1 (9A405)
Kernel Version:      Darwin Kernel Version 11.0.0: Tue Nov  1 20:33:58 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1878.4.46~1/RELEASE_ARM_S5L8930X
Date:                2012-01-01 04:25:33
Time since snapshot: 74 ms

Free pages:        476
Wired pages:       13005
Purgeable pages:   0
Largest process:   MobileSafari

Processes
         Name                 UUID                    Count resident pages
             lsd <5b380bab4f83387fb3c5c3d9de8d5e31>     137
     pasteboardd <89a3457066f6346984e7d56929d128a2>     158
    MobileSafari <586de8c153f93939a9f42bec9d0d8bfd>   31908 (jettisoned) (active)
      MobileMail <7064f2baf3f23db987bc8ec99855fe53>     954 (jettisoned)
        networkd <6ee7a78e56073f6e8db4c2cc3265fdb4>     132
filecoordination <1828dd8176c03a93ba316423dd59e5e5>     135
      aosnotifyd <58089d732ab43bbea0aec4a6f812f446>     371
        BTServer <e03baab8e0103188979ce54b87591065>     317
      aggregated <68a25a1690cb372096543a46abed14d7>     295
            apsd <e4b6e6e4f31e36f79815747ecbf52907>     230
     dataaccessd <b4f61f117ee635c48329af8572733d30>    1004
   fairplayd.K48 <ff02701c98d63606baeff5aa951d59f9>     114
       fseventsd <78af02202422321885dfc85c24534b0e>     422
            iapd <3ee7f82879033b4fb93b9cf1f4ecae29>     295
         imagent <8e2042f2ec9e3af9ba400f031f1bbfa7>     297
       locationd <91c84ab19dd03e4ab1b4cc30178ab1c0>     584
   mDNSResponder <b75f43f012ad3d9ea172d37491994e22>     186
    mediaremoted <b9fa7d1381013c2fa90ea134ff905f59>     191
    mediaserverd <478e5e8345c83be5ba1868906813bb75>     636
             ubd <7eaf0b0ca5b83afabecb0dfaa38c7a19>     661
           wifid <e176ab123beb3000bdb89e020612c1d6>     238
          powerd <25ddef6b52e4385b819e777dd2eeed3c>     131
       lockdownd <a68aa1526ef13a9bb4426bb71ffc1e3c>     206
CommCenterClassi <3ef6d0094b5c39d3b77e558ad3018d24>     282
         syslogd <dd3766bcb1213e91b66283635db09773>      91
     SpringBoard <7506c20d86da3f1dbe9bf38f8bda253d>    5744 (active)
         configd <3430c0025ed13f56800a329b7254d2ae>     277
         notifyd <3793fabace3a385687b3c29c1fa1fcac>     183
  UserEventAgent <6e1cabc1ec6d372c90a6bdeaa7b258fa>     327
         launchd <cc35dd7a872334319ed028e6bbeae081>      98
```

**End**

How do we read this crash log? What can we do in the web app to reduce the crashes? ( it could crash every time we visit the site with a clean boot )

Comment: What exactly is on the website?  What have you tried doing to the website to fix this issue? Is there a mobile optimized version of the site?

Comment: All the crash report tells us is that MobileSafari was killed (and was active) and had 31908 resident pages.  This can be caused by a number of things.

Comment: @Ivan I can speak for my case. I have done a good number of memory leak optimization with Google Chrome Heap Debugger and I am still having LowMemory crash along the line of what is posted. I would really like to have an answer about how we are suppose to debug those problem or what has to check to prevent this kind of crash. Information about this for web application is no where to found at the moment.

Comment: I have had similar problems with a site, which intensively used dynamic content, that is there was a lot of AJAX calls bringing data for page updates every second. If this is also true for your case, try to minimize manipulations with DOM and page resources as much a possible. Perhaps, switching from AJAX to WebSockets may help as well.